# Difference between two string columns in Snowflake

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a table in following form;

```
Boutique_sk|'Test'|'Column'
 167203    |1002.43| 2345.67
 12345     |234.67 | 123.45
 .....
```

The goal is to make a new column having difference between 'Test' and 'Control' values. Here is my SQL query for it;

```
SELECT boutique_sk,
    ''Control''- ''Test''  AS diff
FROM pivoted
```

I tried to escape the single quotes in the column name. But I am getting following error message;

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 83 at position 17 unexpected ''''.
```

Can I get some help here, how to rectify this error?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query is what you are looking for. If you look at the column names of the table, all 3 columns have mixed case. Below documentation (as suggested by waldente also) will help you understand how mixed case identifiers are handled.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html

select "Boutique_sk",
"Control"-"Test" as diff from pivoted;

Answer (score 2):

Try double quotes:

```
SELECT boutique_sk,
    "Control"- "Test"  AS diff
FROM pivoted
```

Update -- Also checkout the [QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#third-party-tools-and-case-insensitive-identifier-resolution)

Comment: Actually, it is giving me an error, Invalid identifier '"Control"'

Comment: You can replace Control with the column name you want.  The quotes are letting you specify columns with lower case and special chars.

Comment: I think you want `"'Control'"- "'Test'"`. there are single quotes as part of the names of the columns, and the double quotes allow you to include those special characters as waldente suggests..